# Count Posts In A WP Taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I have this code in my functions PHP file which I made from searching forums:

```
function sc_estio_project_management_count() {
  echo '<div class="estio-counter" style="background-color: #FF5000";>We currently have<br />' . '<span class="estio-counter-span">' . esc_html( get_tag(210)->count ) . '</span>' . '<br />vacancies in<br />Project <br id="estio-counter-break"/>Management<br /><br /><a href="/training/job-type/project-management/">View all vacancies</a></div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'estio_project_management_count', 'sc_estio_project_management_count' );
```

The `. esc_html( get_tag(210)->count ) .` is great & currently echos out the number of posts within a custom post type. Currently there are 8 job types within the post type, each with an individual ID, i.e the above is '210' so on my front end this says there are currently X amount of jobs available in Project Management.

Can anyone help how I can add all these post 8 job type counts together so I can make a shortcode which echos out the total number of posts? I.e 'We currently have a total of X jobs available')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say the jobs are tucked in a post: Wordpress has a function called wp_count_posts

```
$count_posts = wp_count_posts( 'jobs' )->publish ;
```

So for example, you can do a count on the CPT jobs that are published like above example. The 'Jobs' is the CPT you want to count

For more reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_count_posts

Comment: That's perfect, many thanks! Any idea how to fix the taxonomy post count? The count says there are 3 posts in one of the job types but there are only 2. There are no trashed or draft ones.